# How to Click on Search button in Google Search using Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
package selrcdemo;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ById;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class rcdemo {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver; // declare webdriver instance
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Cheitrav\\Desktop\\ISTQB\\chromedriver.exe"); // set driver path
    driver =new ChromeDriver(); // instantiate new firefox driver

    driver.get("https://www.google.com"); // open google.com

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");

    //Insert code here to locate and click on Search button


    }

}
```

Comment: Not able to locate Search button of google search

Answer (score 4):

You can use linkText to find the search button on the Google Search page.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Search")).click();
```

you can also search by simulating Enter Button click on the search text box, after entering the text to search.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css selector like:

```
input[type=submit]
```

or

```
input[name=btnK]
```

or

```
form input[type=submit]
```

Or you can try to search by name `btnK` in case it will never change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to click on the search button.

```
//Insert code here to locate and click on Search button
driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Right Answer is**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");

driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to be click, you can take page with "submit"

For example;

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys("keyword")
search_box.submit()

and then browser goes to results :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use **XPath** like:

```
(//input[@value='Google Search'])[2]
```